# row_number based on case when with text content

Tags: sql

Here is a task I need to get three elements based on the given conditions:
three elements: user_id, order_time, ordered_subject

1. each unique user_id
2. earliest order_time
3. ordered_subjects' order should be app-> acc ->ayy
4. if there are several order_time are the same, you should take only one subject followed by the 3rd requirement

original table: user_order

| user_id | order_time | ordered_subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001-02-09 | app |
| 2 | 2001-02-09 | app |
| 3 | 2001-02-10 | ayy |
| 1 | 2001-02-09 | acc |
| 1 | 2001-02-10 | app |
| 4 | 2001-02-08 | ayy |
| 5 | 2001-02-09 | acc |
| 5 | 2001-02-09 | ayy |

expected table:

| user_id | order_time | ordered_subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001-02-09 | app |
| 2 | 2001-02-09 | app |
| 3 | 2001-02-10 | ayy |
| 4 | 2001-02-08 | ayy |
| 5 | 2001-02-09 | acc |

I come up with the idea of **case when** and **row_number() over**, but it doesn't work

the code I tried:

```
select 
a.uid, 
a.subject, 
b.min_time,
   (case when "app" then 1 
           when "acc" then 2 
           when "ayy" then 3 
           else 4 end) as rn, 
   row_number() over(partition by 
                       concat(uid,order_id) 
                       order by 
                       rn)
from (
   select uid, min(order_time) as min_time
   from user_order
   group by
   uid
   ) as b
-- join
user_order as a
-- on
where
a.uid = b.uid
and
b.min_time = a.order_time
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Your query doesn't match sample data. Please correct.

Comment: Please always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using. I'Ve posted a standard SQL answer that works in most RDBMS, but not in all.

Comment: Your CASE syntax is incorrect; you must either use CASE *expression* WHEN *value* THEN *expression* ...END, or CASE WHEN *boolean* THEN *expression* ... END.

Comment: And please never say "but it doesn't work". Tell us in what regard it doesn't work. Are you getting an error message? Which? Or too many rows, too few, none at all, wrong ones, ...? Explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want one result row per user. Per user you want the earliest order and if there is more than one order on the earliest date you prefer the order subject app over acc and acc over ayy.

You want to use `ROW_NUMBER`, so partition by user ID and order by date and the order subject in the desired order.

```
select user_id, order_time, ordered_subject
from
(
  select
    user_id, order_time, ordered_subject,
    row_number() over
      (partition by user_id
       order by order_time,
                case ordered_subject
                  when 'app' then 1
                  when 'acc' then 2
                  when 'ayy' then 3
                  else 4
                end) as rn
  from mytable
) numbered
where rn = 1
order by user_id;
```